# How do I find images inside an image?

Tags: c#, emgucv

How do I find images inside an image?

Right now I'm using EmguCV and I have cooked up the following code based on this Tutorial:
https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp

```
        using (UMat gray = new UMat())
        using (UMat cannyEdges = new UMat())
        {
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(img, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
            CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(3, 3), 2);
            CvInvoke.Canny(gray, cannyEdges, 0, 10, 3);

            LineSegment2D[] lines = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(
                cannyEdges,
                1, //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
                Math.PI / 2, //Angle resolution measured in radians.
                0, //threshold
                40, //min Line width
                1); //gap between lines


            foreach (LineSegment2D line in lines)
            {
                CvInvoke.Line(img, line.P1, line.P2, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar, 1);
            }
        }
```

Step 1
[image]
Step 2
[image]
Step 3
[image]

This is my best result so far, but it's not perfect since i still need some edges to be able to create all bounding boxes around the images.

Step 4
[image]

What I want, is to find all edges of every single images in the image so I can make perfect bounding boxes like so.
[image: The red areas are what i want to find]

I'm new to EmguCV/OpenCV, but i still think my best bet is on this library for solving this problem.
I just need to find the right tools and use them right, and that's what I hope someone here can help me with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

- Load the image
- Invert - `img.Not()`
- Convert to Grayscale - `img.Convert<Gray,byte>()`
- Perform binary thresholding - `img.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(54), new Gray(255))`

It will result to the following image, optimize the threshold value to get better results:
[image]

- Get the convex hull and bounding box. Perform filtering so you get the objects that fits your criteria. You can use the contour area, perimeter, etc.

  ```
  var Contours = new List<Contour<Point>>();
  for (Contour<Point> contours = _gray.FindContours(
     HAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL); 
     contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
  {
      Seq<Point> pts = contours.GetConvexHull(ORIENTATION.CV_CLOCKWISE);
      double diff = Math.Round(Math.Abs(pts.Area - contours.Area) / 
        pts.Area, 2);

      //additional constraint
      double q = contours.Area / contours.Perimeter;

      //bounding box of the counter
      Rectangle rect = contours.BoundingRectangle;

      //customize the value to suit your need
      if (contours.BoundingRectangle.Height > 5 && 
       contours.BoundingRectangle.Width > 5)
      {
          Contours.Add(contours);
      }
  }
  ```
- Do what you want with `Contours`, (e.g. fill and use as mask to extract each image, draw bounding box, etc.)

Comment: Thanks!
I have made a working prototype from your example and it works great.
but there is a problem because if the background is black instead of white like this one https://ibb.co/GxVgJ80 then it wont work any more. I have found out that i can solve it by not invert it, but how can i know if i have to invert it or not?

Comment: you can count the number of black pixel or white pixel, set a threshold, then choose whether to invert the image or not.

Comment: The threshold can be a total count of black pixels as percentage of the total image, say 20% or 0.20. You can then choose to invert the image or not if this condition is satisfied.